# What can be said about $f$ when $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$, we have $f(z_0) = z_0$ and $f^\prime(z_0) = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am solving a problem in Complex Analysis. This problem arose as a subproblem in my solution.

Let $f: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be an analytic function. Suppose for some $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$, we have $f(z_0) = z_0$ and $f^\prime(z_0) = 1$. What can we say that $f$?

Sinec $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ then we can use the Schwarz-pick lemma, that is $|f^\prime (a)| \leq \frac{1-|f(a)|^2}{1-|a|^2}$ for all $a\in \mathbb{D}$.

Moreover, in this case equality holds. We know that equality holds in Schwarz -pick lemma iff $f \in \text{Aut} (\mathbb{D})$.

$\textbf{Conclusion:}$ $f$ is an automorphism.

Am I correct?

Comment: Do you know Schwarz lemma?

Comment: @Didier Yes I know. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Didier, Am I right now?

Comment: Seems right specifying $a=z_0$